# Attach or sync in one to many relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, relation

Question Model:

```
$this->hasMany('App\Option');
```

Option Model:

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Question');
```

Question Controller

```
$question = new Question;
$question->question = 'Question';
$question->options()->attach(['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4']);
```

I'm trying to attach the options data, but it says error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()"

How to attach and sync that in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$question = new Question;
$question->question = 'Question';
$question->save(); // Model should be saved before attaching children
$question->options()->saveMany([
    new Option(['name' => 'option1'),
    new Option(['name' => 'option2'),
    new Option(['name' => 'option3')
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Relationship one to many does not have method `attach()`.`attach()` method working only for relationship `ManytoMany`. You can just use `id` one of your model.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.